# Is there any chance to use C++ for Web applications in the future?

Tags: c++

Coming from Python and Javascript background, I'd like to know if there is any chance to use C++ for Web applications in the future.

I mean...if C++ is only for Desktop applications and mostly Game Engines or Operation Systems, then how you can guarantee future of this language?, I know C++ is unbeatable for many tasks today, and it's very popular, but we can't really use it for Web, can we?

This is not language war and I'm not bashing C++ and this is not Desktop-vs-Web debate...I'm just curious to know where this language going in this ocean of chaos!

Sorry for language

Comment: I can appreciate that you are curious. The pratical answer is "No". It's not practical to use C++ for web applications; because it's just unncessary, and the API doesn't exist for it to be fast. It's a potentially argumentative topic, so this thread may get closed. But generally, in selecting a web language, you want a framework that does a bunch of stuff for you. C++ just doesn't have this background, hence you don't see it being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does ASP.NET support C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615215/does-asp-net-support-c)

Comment: @Ndv: As per [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), your question is quite subjective. You don't seem to have an actual problem to solve, and the question it's open-ended, hypothetical, and more than likely results in opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a C++ web application toolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) that you can use right now. There's [at least one site](http://www.okcupid.com/about/technology) which was implemented in C++. Facebook has [a tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP) that converts PHP code into C++, which is compiled with GCC, and their servers run the executable.

So it's definitely possible to use C++ in some form for web applications. It's not as common as, say PHP, but you can make it work.

Comment: I'm trying to read your question in a way such that this answer applies to it. The answer is good, the question less so. Why didn't you just ask for recommendations for a web application framework for C++?

Answer (score 3):

And.... what are Python and JavaScript implemented in?

:)

(Well CPython is implemented in C, not C++.)

Comment: People never think of this. "Java is the best language ever C++ is obsolete... Oh wait Java is written in C++"

Comment: Yeah, so by your logic all websites are written in atoms.

Comment: The original poster was implying that C++ will die because it has no web application.  I was simply pointing out that it does not have a direct web application, but it supports a lot of the languages' implementations that do.  Similarly, Seth Carnegie was pointing out that people forget about language's implementations in this manner a lot.  (Edit: this was @ Noon Silk, not Ndv)

Comment: @Ndv They are indirectly used in the web though. Apache? nginx? Lighttpd? CPython? Java (JSP)? PHP? Perl?  All C or C++ dependent.

Comment: @Noon +1 and yes, that is exactly what I mean. So atoms will never go out of style. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

why not? C++ is a future language, it is versatile and you can get really god performance. And you already can code webservices in java, why not c++?

Answer (score 0):

Boy, first of all you please read this post and the links listed there from CodeProject and other sites:

[Does ASP.NET support C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615215/does-asp-net-support-c)

then your assumptions that C++ is mostly for Games and OS are very vague and not really reflecting the truth.

C++ is a language that is there to stay, don't be afraid it won't develop only because it's less used in web development.

I could simplify a lot telling that the web probably would not run without it, not many web servers are done in Managed .NET languages so without C++, no web!

IE is not done in C#, Windows neither, Matlab neither, AutoCAD neither...

let's do not start language war, simply read the other question I linked above :)